# How to add encounter using Fhir R4 by c#

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I've tried add new encounter but it shows "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'". Heare is my code:

```
private static void AddEncounter()
    {
        
        var encount = new Encounter();
        
        encount.Identifier.Add(new Identifier
        {
            Use = (Identifier.IdentifierUse?)1,
            System = "http://www.amc.nl/zorgportal/identifiers/visits",
            Value = "tek001"

        }) ;
        encount.Class = new Coding("http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActCode", "SS", "Lưu trú ngắn hạn");
        encount.Status = 0;
        encount.Priority = new CodeableConcept("http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-ActPriority", "R", "routine");
        encount.Subject = new ResourceReference("Patient/a07b880381ec44ad8f80743f396c8011/_history/1", "Lâm");

        encount.Length.Value = 120;
        encount.Length.Unit = "min";
        encount.Length.System = "http://unitsofmeasure.org";
        encount.Length.Code = "min";
        encount.ReasonCode.Add(new CodeableConcept("http://snomed.info/sct", "184004", "Rối loạn nhịp tim rút"));

        
        encount.Hospitalization.PreAdmissionIdentifier.Use = (Identifier.IdentifierUse?)1;
        encount.Hospitalization.PreAdmissionIdentifier.System = "http://www.amc.nl/zorgportal/identifiers/pre-admissions";
        encount.Hospitalization.PreAdmissionIdentifier.Value = "1598753";
        encount.Hospitalization.AdmitSource = new CodeableConcept("http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/admit-source", "outp", "Khoa ngoại trú");
        encount.Hospitalization.DischargeDisposition = new CodeableConcept("http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/discharge-disposition", "hosp", "Bệnh nhân đã được xuất viện và chăm sóc giảm nhẹ");


        Console.WriteLine("Successful");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

How can i add an exactly?

Comment: Where do you get the NRE?

Comment: I get in Length and Hospitalization.

Comment: Please share the entire `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you do with creating the Identifier for the Identifier field and the other complex objects for the Class, Priority and Subject fields, you will need to create a Duration for the Length field:

```
encount.Length = new Duration();
encount.Length.Value = 120;
// etc.
```

You will have to do this for all of the complex objects you use in your code, so also for the Hospitalization field and the PreAdmissionIdentifier:

```
encount.Hospitalization = new Encounter.HospitalizationComponent();
encount.Hospitalization.PreAdmissionIdentifier = new Identifier();
// etc.
```

Another change I would like to advice, is to make use of the values provided in the enum for the identifier use, to make your code more readable and your intention clear:

```
encount.Hospitalization.PreAdmissionIdentifier.Use = Identifier.IdentifierUse.Official;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help with my project.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say for certain without seeing the entire `class` but **`System.NullReferenceException` is thrown when trying to access something that has not been instantiated.**

`encount.Hospitalization` is likely a reference to another `class` which must first be instantiated. **Try first creating and instance before accessing** (example below).

```
encount.Length = new Length();
encount.Hospitalization = new Hospitalization();
```

**Note**: I'm guessing the `class` names (`Length` and `Hospitalization`) so you may need to adjust for your code. The main idea is that you must create the `class` (`new ...()`) before utilizing\accessing.